# Storing input in Android in Json and displaying the data using RecyclerView

Tags: android, json, kotlin

I am attempting to create a survey app in Android using Kotlinn that collects health data:

1. Enter a list of user data (Name, Age, Weight, Height, Blood Type)
2. Have those information stored in a JSON file
3. Display the data already inputted on the same page as the form. User should be able to remove a row of data

I would be very grateful if you could point me to the correction direction for this.

Comment: Can you elaborate who Enters a list of user data

Comment: That would be the user of the app who would be going to multiple persons whose data are being entered

Comment: You can you recyclerview with different item types for this with drag swipe functionallity to edit/delete the row. Instead of searching and writing all boilerplate code for this, I suggest you use this library instead https://github-com.translate.goog/CymChad/BaseRecyclerViewAdapterHelper/blob/master/readme/5-BaseSectionQuickAdapter.md?_x_tr_sl=auto&_x_tr_tl=en&_x_tr_hl=en-GB